# local variable 'form' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, обработка-ошибок

**views.py** :

```
def edit(request, news_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            a = Laba.objects.get(pk=news_id)
            f = LabaForm(request.POST, instance=a)
            f.save()
            return redirect('/LR/')

    form = LabaForm()           
    return render(request, 'LR/edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Данный код вызывается кликом по кнопке:

```
  <form  method="post" action="edit/{{result.id}}/">{% csrf_token %}<input type="submit" value="Редактировать данные" /></form>
```

При нажатие на кнопку возвращается ошибка:

> local variable 'form' referenced before assignment

Я понимаю, что ошибка связанна с фрагментом `form = LabaForm()` , но как исправить не пойму.

Comment: У вас form сначала используется `if form.is_valid()`, а только потом присваивается: `form = LabaForm()`, нет?..

Comment: Да, правильно, а должно наоборот или как?

Comment: По идее, сначала должно присваиваться значение, потом использоваться переменная.

Comment: @Константин, вы сначала проверяете на валидность несуществующий объект, а потом уже создаете объект, конечно же будет выдаваться ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def edit(request, news_id):
    try:
        a = Laba.objects.get(pk=news_id)
    except Lada.DoesNotExist:
        a = None # тут, либо возвращай что объект не найден

    if a and request.method == 'POST':
        form = LabaForm(request.POST, instance=a)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/LR/')

    form = LabaForm()           
    return render(request, 'LR/edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло, оказывается всё было так просто.